# url open returns errors on some websites and not others

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to gather some data, while looking through examples, some websites work and other's don't. This is an example code I'm getting errors on.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
page_url = "https://www.basspro.com/shop/en"
uClient = uReq(page_url)
```

This returns a whole bunch of errors including "return opener.open(url, data, timeout)"

But when i change the URL to something like `page_url = "https://store.google.com/"`
it works fine.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send appropriate headers along with the request. Send User-Agent.

```
import requests

page_url = "https://www.basspro.com/shop/en"

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)

print(res.status_code)
```

Output:

```
200
```